# Creating a PDF and sending by email

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am looking at the ablity for users to enter some information into a form and send it via `mail()`.

What I'd like is for the details to be sent as a PDF attachment. Possibly with the name of the the sender and a date/time. `test_user_06052011.pdf`

I have a design for the PDF, but I'm not sure how I'd integrate this design to create a PDf in PHP.

Does anyone have an examples or ways in which I could do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php

Comment: Welcome to SO, sipher_z! Please stop writing tags in question titles. You've done it for most of your 11 questions. >.<

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal apologies for the tags in the title. I will make sure I don't do this in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into FPDF - http://www.fpdf.org/ - It's free and a great tool for generating PDF's

There is a PDF generator which is recomended by PHP, however it'd very expensive and the name elludes me now, however I've used FPDF several times whith great success.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy way to create PDF server-site is using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). However, you will need a shell access to server to set it up.

To create PDF you need two files: one is PHP which generates HTML you want to convert into PDF. Let's say this is invoice.php:

```
<?php
    $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
?>
<h1>This is invoice <?= $id ?></h1>
<p>some content...</p>
```

And the other one, which will fetch the invoice and convert it into PDF using wkhtmltopdf:

```
<?php

$tempPDF = tempnam( '/tmp', 'generated-invoice' );
$url = 'http://yoursite.xx/invoice.php?id=123';

exec( "wkhtmltopdf  $url  $tempPDF" );

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invoice.pdf');

echo file_get_contents( $tempPDF );
unlink( $tempPDF );
```

Once you have created a PDF file you can also send mail with attachment this way:

```
<?php

$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "mail with attachment";

$att = file_get_contents( 'generated.pdf' );
$att = base64_encode( $att );
$att = chunk_split( $att );

$BOUNDARY="anystring";

$headers =<<<END
From: Your Name <abc@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=$BOUNDARY
END;

$body =<<<END
--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain

See attached file!

--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your-file.pdf"

$att
--$BOUNDARY--
END;

mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Answer (score 4):

Can't find reason for using native `mail()` function today. In mostly trivial situations we can use PHPMailer library, which in OOP style gives us opportunity to send emails even without understanding of header.
The solution even *without saving physical file* is

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
...
$doc = $pdf->Output('S');
$mail->AddStringAttachment($doc, 'doc.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
$mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you made a Fillable PDF with Acrobat, here is a good chunk of code that will help you get started. This code requires the newest version of phpmailer to work, so just download that and put it in a class folder in the same directory you put this code in. Have your pdf form submit to a page with this code.

```
/*  Branden Sueper 2012
//  PDF to Email - PHP 5
//  Includes: PHPMailer 5.2.1
*/
<?php
if(!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    echo "The Application could not be sent. Please save the PDF and email it manually.";
    exit;
}
echo "<html><head></head><body><img src='loading.gif'>";

//Create PDF file with data
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$pdf = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

 $file = $semi_rand . ".pdf"; 
 $handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
 fwrite($handle, $pdf);   
 fclose($handle);
//

require_once('class/class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer(false); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
  $mail->Host       = "mail.xxxxxxx.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com"; // GMAIL username
  $mail->Password   = "xxxxxxxx";            // GMAIL password
  $mail->AddAddress('Recipient@xxxxxxx.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->SetFrom('reply-to-address@xxxxxxx.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'Your Subject';
  $mail->Body = 'Hello!';
  $mail->AddAttachment($file); // attachment
  $mail->Send();

  //Delete the temp pdf file then redirect to the success page
  unlink($file);
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL="success.php">';    
  exit;    
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  //you can either report the errors here or redirect them to an error page
  //using the above META tag
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
  //Verify the temporary pdf file got deleted
  unlink($file);
?>
```

[PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) Just download PHP mailer and adjust the above code to your liking. For more info on how to create a fillable PDF go to http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/create-fillable-pdf-forms.html

Good Luck! I remember spending 3+ days trying to figure out a very similar issue!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete code http://codexhelp.blogspot.in/2017/04/php-email-create-pdf-and-send-with.html

```
    /**/
    $mailto = $_POST['mailto'];
    $mailfrom = $_POST['mailfrom'];
    $mailsubject = $_POST['mailsubject'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];


    $description = wordwrap($description, 100, "<br />");
    /* break description content every after 100 character. */


    $content = '';

    $content .= '
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

 table{
 width:800px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

 td{
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
padding: 10px; 
max-width:520px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}


 </style>

 ';
    /* you css */



    $content .= '<table>';

    $content .= '<tr><td>Mail To</td> <td>' . $mailto . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Mail From</td>   <td>' . $mailfrom . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Mail Subject</td>   <td>' . $mailsubject . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Firstname</td>   <td>' . $firstname . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Lastname</td>   <td>' . $lastname . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Description</td>   <td>' . $description . '</td> </tr>';

    $content .= '</table>';


    require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');


    $to = $mailto;
    $from = $mailfrom;
    $subject = $mailsubject;  

    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');

    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);


    $message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";
    $separator = md5(time());
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $filename = "pdf-document.pdf";
    $pdfdoc = $html2pdf->Output('', 'S');
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));




    $headers = "From: " . $from . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;

    $body = '';

    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol; //had one more .$eol


    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;


    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $attachment . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

        $msgsuccess = 'Mail Send Successfully';
    } else {

        $msgerror = 'Main not send';
    }
```

Comment: awesome i have tried this link demo it's working fine for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, you could also have a look at [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), I use it a lot to create PDFs on the fly from PHP... It has (limited) HTML to PDF functionality built-in and is very easy to use (just look at the examples). And another major benefit : it's still in active development (a bit too active for some probably :p).

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still relevant, so posting it here for the benefit of new visitors to this question.

[PDFMark](https://pdfmark.com) offers an API to generate PDF and can also deliver it on an email. You can create a PDF from HTML and specify an email address, to which the generated PDF will be sent as an attachment.

Disclosure: I am the developer