# PHP send email with PDF Attachment

Tags: php, email, pdf, attachment, send

How to get attachment instead of code in body?
I am trying to send email with a PDF file attachment

```
$to = "$Email";
$email_subject = "Thank You from Admission Cell";
$email_body = "Dear $Name \n Greeting from ........... \n \n ".
"Thank You & Regards \n Admission Cell\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"\"";
$headers = "From: Admission Cell<>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:";
$file = file_get_contents("/file_path/public_html/admission.pdf");
$email_body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

I am getting an email with BODY like this

```
Thank You & Regards
Admission Cell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```

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908706/creating-a-pdf-and-sending-by-email) (second answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHPMailer script.

To use PHPMailer:

1. Download the PHPMailer script from here:
   http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
2. Extract the archive and copy the script's folder to a convenient
   place in your project.
3. Include the main script file --
   require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');

you can find the example here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12302354/4018585